# How to do like search with edismax(extended dismax)

Tags: solr, wildcard

I'm using **solr search** to search the record set. I've given one sample record below.
"New subscription added in the portal"

I've configured the *ExtraParams(CommonQueryOptions)* with *"defType:edismax"* and  also have few *"qf"* (to give the weightage)
I do search like below,
"subscription"

And it is returning that particular record.

But when I search with below text and it returns nothing.
"subscriptio"

What I'm expecting is it should return the same result considering wild card search.

But, when I removed the *defType* and *qf*, it is returning the right result, I mean one record. But, it is not right way of doing and I want the weightage as a must. Can anyone please help me with the problem? Let me know in case you want to understand the problem further.

Comment: What is the resulting URL logged on the Solr side? Does the query work as expected in the query interface under the Solr admin page? (i.e. is the problem with SolrJ usage or the field themselves) What is the actual query and field type since you expect a wildcard search to work without any wildcard qualifier (`*`)?

Comment: You might be confusing the stemming process that Solr does on text fields with "wildcard searching". What kind of field you are searching on?

Comment: I'm doing the search from the solr admin page.
Sample screenshot below,

https://images.app.goo.gl/XSJJ2B1qwS9NHBwL9

q: ("subscriptio")
edismax: checkbox checked
qf: Given few fields with/without weightage

Then I hit the search.
Expected: return recirds that have name or something like  "subscription"
Actual: Returns nothing.

Comment: In case if I remove the boost, i.e., qf: then it is working fine. I mean it is fetching records.